# Difference between Seagate Expansion and GoFlex HDD

Tags: hard-drive, seagate, expansion

What are the significant differences between [Seagate Expansion Portable 1 TB USB 3.0 (Model STAX1000302)](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-au/products/external/expansion/expansion_portable/) and [Seagate Free Agent GoFlex 1TB USB 3.0 (Model STAA1000302)](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-au/products/external/external-hard-drive/portable-hard-drive/) except Data Encryption? I found Expansion models are cheaper.

Regards,

Arindam

Comment: We have a [faq]. As a new user, a blue banner prompted you to read it before you asked this question. Read it before you ask your next one.

Comment: @MDMarra: Sorry for the question I have asked at wrong place. Thanks for the advise. I'll post it at 'Super User'. Cheers.

Comment: This is the definition of "Too Localized". Asking for specific product recommendations like this will likely get your topic closed anywhere in the network. It wouldn't hurt to try asking it there, but don't be surprised if it's closed just as fast.

Answer (score 5):

The output of:

```
diff -u <(lynx -dump http://www.seagate.com/www/en-au/products/external/expansion/expansion_portable/) <(lynx -dump http://www.seagate.com/www/en-au/products/external/external-hard-drive/portable-hard-drive/)
```

tells it all:

```
-Seagate® Expansion™ Portable Drives
+FreeAgent® GoFlex™ Ultra–portable Drive

-A basic drive that goes wherever you do.
+This ultra–upgradable, ultra–portable hard drive makes it ultra–easy for you
+to store, backup, encrypt and access your files anytime, anywhere.

-     * Available with USB 2.0 or 3.0 plug–and–play connectivity.
-     * Transport files from one computer to another.
-     * Carry data wherever you need it.
+     * Features USB 2.0 or 3.0 plug–and–play connectivity
+     * Includes pre–loaded easy–to–use backup software
+     * Lets you upgrade to USB 3.0, FireWire^® 800 or eSATA
+     * Allows you to access your content on your TV, network and on–the–go
+       when combined with other GoFlex devices
```

Comment: +1 for gratuitous use of `diff`

Comment: @ArindamBanerjee HE IS A TRUE SCHOLAR AND GENTLEMAN!